# How to check special characters in a string for different countries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to check that the strings coming from my form contain special characters (@#$% & *!/), including characters from countries like China, Bulgaria, Russia, Greece and others that are not in the Latin alphabet.
The intention is to find a solution that does not harm the user experience and that brings security to the system.
I found some solutions using reGex, but they don't include characters from these other countries.
Is there any library or solution for this?

Comment: Regex would be your best option, instead of searching for characters you don't want, search the characters you do want (your alphabet), then just negate the expression, despite of regex, you could use the :https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/String/ascii_only%3F method and use some exceptions to some other characters that are not in ascii

,I think searching for a gem is overkill, regex is made for that purpose

Comment: How do you define "special" characters? For example, do you consider the second character in my first name "special"? Because I don't, I consider it to be a perfectly normal character. And how do you define a character to be from a certain country? For example, the second character in my first name is used in German (and thus in Germany, Austria, part of Switzerland, but also part of Texas and Pennsylvania, as well as part of Denmark), in French (and thus in France, parts of Canada, parts of Louisiana), but it can also be used in English in words like coöperation.

Comment: Being Swedish I consider Ö to be the 29th letter in the alphabet. And besides the three extra letter that we use beyond the latin alphabet we also use diacritics in a whole host of loanwords like `café` - my point being that its stupid to make any kind of assumptions.

Comment: Jörg W Mittag I consider special characters to be characters like: @#$%&*!/ and other characters that can be used to perform malicious activities on my system.
My difficulty has been exactly to find a solution not to harm the users' experience.

Comment: @Bruno This is an exceptionally broad question. It covers pretty much most of Unicode.